# C++ | How can I break this inter-class dependency issue?

Tags: c++, class-design

I provide to you a MWE:

```
#include <iostream>


class C;


class A
{
    public:

    A(C &cc)
        : c(cc)
    {
    }

    int functionA()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    C &c;
};


class B
{
    public:

    B(C &cc)
        : c(cc)
    {
    }

    int functionB()
    {
        return c.a.functionA();
    }

    C &c;
};


class C
{
    public:

    C()
        : a(*this)
        , b(*this)
    {
    }

    int functionC()
    {
        return b.functionB();
    }

    A a;
    B b;
};


int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << c.functionC() << std::endl;
}
```

And associated compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘int B::functionB()’:
main.cpp:37:16: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class C’
   37 |         return c.a.functionA();
      |                ^
main.cpp:5:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class C’
    5 | class C;
      |       ^
```

Further explanation is probably not required, however, the `class C` is not fully defined by the time we reach line `return c.a.functionA()`.

What is the most appropriate way to break this interdependence problem?

If it helps to guide, then consider the following context

```
C = Host
A = CPU
B = RAM
```

and the actual code where this problem occurs in my project is

```
void CPU::MemFetchByte(byte &ret, const addr_t addr)
{
    HardwareDevice::host.memory.GetByte(ret, addr);
}
```

perhaps this is useful additional info, perhaps it is not.

Additionally, I tried to invert the problem as follows

```
#include <iostream>


//class C;
class A;
class B;



class C
{
    public:

    C()
        : a(new A(*this))
        , b(new B(*this))
    {
    }

    ~C()
    {
        delete b;
        delete a;
    }

    int functionC()
    {
        return b->functionB();
    }

    A *a;
    B *b;
};


class A
{
    public:

    A(C &cc)
        : c(cc)
    {
    }

    int functionA()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    C &c;
};


class B
{
    public:

    B(C &cc)
        : c(cc)
    {
    }

    int functionB()
    {
        return c.a->functionA();
    }

    C &c;
};


int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << c.functionC() << std::endl;
}
```

however this (as expected) makes things worse not better:

```
main.cpp:16:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A’
   16 |         : a(new A(*this))
      |                        ^
main.cpp:6:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class A’
    6 | class A;
      |       ^
main.cpp:17:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class B’
   17 |         , b(new B(*this))
      |                        ^
main.cpp:7:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class B’
    7 | class B;
      |       ^
```

Comment: doesnt using a pointer solve your problem? that way, instantialization will be postponed until runtime if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Split declarations and implementations.

Comment: @Rika You suggest changing the reference to `C` in `A` and `B` to a pointer, or suggest changing `a` and `b` in `C` to pointers?

Comment: While pointers and references can exist just based on forward declarations, using them to call methods requires the full declaration of the class to be included. That leads to the recommendations others have given to separate implementations from declarations.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `std::unique_ptr<A> a; std::unique_ptr<B> b;` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why?

Comment: @user3728501 Because you get a lot for free. 1) You wouldn't need to write a destructor. 2) You wouldn't need to define the copy constructor and copy assignment operator as `delete`d (which you have forgotten so your class is rather unsafe). 3) The move constructor and move assignment operator would work without the need to manually implement them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh alright then. You make a compelling argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with complete types by moving the constructors and member function implementations out of the class declarations.

```
#include <iostream>

class A;
class B;
class C;

class A { 
public:
    A(C &cc);
    int functionA();
    C &c; 
};
class B { 
public:
    B(C &cc);
    int functionB();
    C &c; 
};
class C { 
public:
    C();
    int functionC();
    A a;
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << c.functionC() << std::endl;
}

A::A(C &cc) : c(cc)
{ }

int A::functionA() {
    return 0;
}

B::B(C &cc) : c(cc)
{ }

int B::functionB() {
    return c.a.functionA();
}

C::C() : a(*this), b(*this)
{ }

int C::functionC() {
    return b.functionB();
}
```

Comment: The constructors don't have to move. The *only change required* is to move `functionB` out after `C`.

Comment: Ok yes, it's quite simple I can see how this works, thanks

Comment: Clearly I was just having a mental block here

Comment: Ah ok, it is slightly more complicated, due to me having multiple files. I may have to edit the question

Comment: Update: Nope it's fine, just required a few extra includes in the right places

Answer (score 1):

```
int functionB()
{
    return c.a.functionA();
}
```

This function needs to be defined outside of the class body, *after* `class C` is defined.

---

You can apply the same idea to your second attempt (the definitions for  `C()`, `~C()`, and `functionC()` will need to be moved). But this is worse than your first attempt, because you're using heap allocation for no good reason (and `class C` doesn't follow the rule of three).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like classes `A` and `B` are parts of system `C`, so that another option is to compose `C` from `A` and `B` using derivation. This allows `A` and `B` to get to `C` with a simple downcast, no `C& c` member is required:

```
struct C;

struct A {
    void fa();
};

struct B {
    void fb();
};

struct C : A, B {
    void fc();
};

void A::fa() {
    static_cast<C&>(*this).fc();
}

void B::fb() {
    static_cast<C&>(*this).fc();
}
```